# DB2 error: SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved. Reason code: "3"

Tags: db2, dbeaver

I get the following error when trying to connect to a db2 db:

```
$ /opt/ibm/db2/V10.5/bin/db2 connect to SRVO
SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".
```

However I don't experience any problems when connecting to it from **DBeaver**. What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: You need to dot in the correct `db2profile` file into your shell session before you run the `db2` command.  For example `. ~db2inst1/sqllib/db2profile` (where your Db2-instance-name is db2inst1) , use the correct instance-name for your environment.  When you dot in this file , all the required environment variables will be set correctly including the PATH, so you don't need to be in a specific directory to be able to run the `db2` command. Normally you do this dotting in via your shell startup file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The message says:

> SQL1390C  The environment variable DB2INSTANCE is not defined or is
> invalid.

and the SQL10007 is also returned because of this - so fix the DB2INSTANCE by setting it to your current instance.

```
set  DB2INSTANCE=whateveryourinstanceis
```

Addition:
Your driver seetting within DBeaver should point to the correct location of following files:
db2java.zip
db2jcc_license_cu.jar (or similar)
db2jcc4.jar

Comment: Yes. I've already solved it with 
`$ DB2INSTANCE=db2inst1
$ export DB2INSTANCE`

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue in one of my Ansible roles, which executes sql scripts for an application. It occurs after I upgraded DB2 from 11.1.0 to 11.1.4.5 (latest supported version for the software I'm using).

Setting the `DB2INSTANCE` environment variable didn't help. By manually login as the instance user, I saw that there were a bunch of more variables from DB2:

```
[db2inst1@cnx-db2 ~]$ env | grep -i db2 | wc -l
16
```

But there is a script `~/sqllib/db2profile` which sets all the relevant env variables. Calling it like this works in my Ansible role:

```
- name: "Check and create DBs for CNX with user {{ db2.instance.name }}"
  become: yes
  become_user: "{{ db2.instance.name }}"
  shell: |
    . ~/sqllib/db2profile
    apps=("activities" "blogs" "cognos" "communities" "dogear" "files" "forum" "homepage" "mobile" "profiles" "metrics" "pushnotification" "wikis")
    for app in ${apps[*]}
    do
      {{ db2.target }}/bin/db2 -td@ -vf {{ cnx_sql_dir }}/${app}/db2/createDb.sql
      {{ db2.target }}/bin/db2 -td@ -vf {{ cnx_sql_dir }}/${app}/db2/appGrants.sql
    done
```