# DB2 LUW "set db2instance" in Windows Shell not working properly

Tags: cmd, db2-luw

I am an experienced database administrator with IBM DB2 LUW and I am constantly running into the following problem. Any hint would be highly appreciated. We are running DB2 V 11.1.4070 on this machine.

We have a Windows server running DB2 on four instances. We need to backup the databases on a regular basis. We are using the external software Dataprotector for backing up the databases on an external storage device. We are using CMD-Batchfiles to execute the backup.

The problem I have is the following. In the first line I need to set the value of the OS-Variable "db2instance" to the value of the actual instance I need to backup.

This reads something like this

```
set db2instance=INSTANCE1

db2 connect to database1
db2 quiesce database
db2 connect reset
db2 deactivate database database1

Call Dataprotector 

db2 activate database database1
db2 connect to database1
db2 unquiesce database
db2 connect reset
```

The problem I am running into is: the `set db2instance` statement isn't executed every time.

Sometimes it is executed fine, some other time it is not excecuted and some times it is executed but afterwards the shell gets corrupted and any db2 statement yields #

```
SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "6"
```

Problem seems to be related somewhat to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64661211/db2-error-sql10007n-message-1390-could-not-be-retrieved-reason-code-3)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: stackoverflow is about programming, so we need to __see your code__ in your question.  Specifically does your code defensively check all exit-codes and react appropriately, and does your code run `db2 terminate` before changing DB2INSTANCE? (essential). It also matters if the instances are at different db2levels. The SQL1007N happens when the environment variables are incorrect at that moment.

Comment: The code is included, it is simplfied and does not include the call to the backup tool. Entering db2 terminate does not work in the command line, afterwards the instance is set to our default instance. For clarification I will include db2 in the code

Comment: That code is guaranteed to fail and is unfit for production use. The `db2 terminate` is essential before changing DB2INSTANCE. "does not work" is not a valid description of a problem

Comment: For clarification: 1) set db2 instance=INSTANCE1 2) db2 terminate 3) db2 get instance yields at step 3 another instance as the one which was set.  Hope that helps, thank you so far

Comment: The idea is that before changing the DB2INSTANCE value, there should be no db2bp process running in your current process tree for the previous instance. The `db2 terminate` will close the db2bp if it is running. So whenever you are finished with one instance, run `db2 terminate` , and before changing DB2INSTANCE

Comment: This sounds legitimate and is looking good when executed in Command Window (without Backup-Part). I will get back here soon for feedback. Thank you     --- UPDATE --- it does not work in the script. Will change to Powershell

Comment: I solved this problem by switching from CMD to Powershell